# Psuedo Random numbers in WC3 Map Editor?

Tags: random

As I'm trying to write a random hero function in the WC3 Map Editor I've discovered that the built in GUI code for generating a Random number is not so random. Its a disgusting repeating Pseudo Random line. Every time the trigger is run it generates the same sequence of numbers no matter how many times the trigger is ran.

Is there a way to generate a more random looking set of numbers?

```
Actions
-Set randomInt[(Player number of (Owner of (Sold Unit)))] = (Random integer number between 1 and 10)
-Game - Display to (All Players) the text: (String(randomInt[(Player number of (Owner of (Sold Unit)))]))
```

I have no problem with the Pseudo Random concept, but it doesn't generate a new line of Pseudo Random whenever the game starts. Now my real problem is that I'm deployed in Afghanistan and all of the WC3 Map Making communities are blocked. Does anyone know how to generate a more random sequence of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.hiveworkshop.com/forums/map-development-202/wc3s-random-number-generator-21161/):

> That only happens when you play the
>   map through the "test map" feature in
>   the world editor. It will always
>   generate the same variables, even if
>   random. If you really want to test
>   triggers with random
>   variables/numbers, play the map
>   normally by opening wc3 and selecting
>   the map in-game.

Comment: Well that's horribly inefficient and a nuisance. Thank you, I was stuck on that for a while now.

Also if you restart mission you'll generate the same pseudorandom line.  I guess it doesn't generate a new one when you restart it from inside the game.

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in the map editor for that, generate random by using same seed.